# Confused on ls command that lists absolute paths of directories

Tags: linux, bash, glob

I found code online that lists the absolute paths of all directories in the current directory:

> ls -d "$PWD"/*

The code works as expected, but I'm confused on how it works and the function of "/*" at the end.

Answer (score 1):

First, `ls -d` doesn't only list the absolute paths of all directories in the current directory. It also lists non-directories. The `-d` tells `ls` to not list the contents of directories. `-d` doesn't tell `ls` to exclude files. For example, imagine the current directory contains one directory named "dir", and "dir" contains three files:

```
ls dir
# output:
file1 file2 file3

ls -d dir
# output:
dir

ls -d dir/*
# output:
file1 file2 file3
```

If you want to find only directories, instead try `find "$PWD"/* -type d` (includes subdirectories) or `find "$PWD"/* -maxdepth 0 -type d` (doesn't include subdirectories).

What about `"$PWD"/*`? `PWD` is a variable whose value is the current working directory. So, if you are in `/home/anthony`, the value of `PWD` is `/home/anthony`. `$PWD` tells `bash` to use the value of `PWD`, so typing `$PWD/*` is more or less equivalent to typing `/home/anthony/*`.

What about the double-quotes in `"$PWD"/*`? Those are there in case the path to the current directory contains problematic characters, e.g., spaces. For example, imagine the working directory is `/home/anthony/My Documents`:

```
ls $PWD
# output:
ls: cannot access '/home/anthony/My': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'Documents': No such file or directory

ls "$PWD"
# output:
file1 file2 etc...
```

What about the `/` in `"$PWD"/*`? `"$PWD"*` without the `/` also matches paths like `/home/anthony1`, not only files inside of the directory `/home/anthony`.